# Useless ellipsis is useless in chat

Tags: discussion, support, chat, design

In chat an ellipsis is displayed to display more avatars in the list however sometimes when you click it it only expands to one extra avatar which is kinda... useless :-)

[image: you are a useless ellipsis!]

Not really a huge bug, but it kinda annoys me for some time now (I know I know).

Comment: How do you want it to behave?

Comment: If it is only there to hide/show a single avatar it shouldn't be there. Because the space it takes to show the ellipsis might as well just show the avatar :-)

Comment: @balpha fixit fixit fixit

Comment: Why is this tagged under bug ?

Comment: The current algorithm display the first 32 avatars. `32` is a nice round number, whereas `33` is not even a prime.

Comment: @phpNoOb Because it *is* a terrible bug and it needs to be resolved as fast as possible, IT'S SUPER URGENT!

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 Which bothers you more the Ellipsis or Me?

Comment: I'm going to change my avatar to an ellipsis and just lurk in the chat from now on just to annoy @PeeHaa埽 =oP

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The current algorithm displays the first 32 avatars and elipsis if there are more: 33 items in total. Isn't that ugly?

Comment: @Jasper, that's still 32 avatars and one ellipsis (cryptic ツ's plans notwithstanding). I can live with it.

Comment: Okay, if we fix this by displaying 33 avatars at once instead of 32, what about if there are 34 avatars? There would be still an ellipsis showing only one more, right? Sorry, but this is not really well thought out.

Comment: @Chichiray actually it is, but you don't get it ;-) When there are 33 avatars just display it. When there are 34 or more display 32 and show the ellipsis. The "see more" is to prevent the avatar list taking up too much space (at least that's how I see it)

Comment: Hm, that makes perhaps sense.